# Intuition on independence-like condition

Tags: probability, probability-theory, intuition, independence

Consider a set of $n$ bounded, non-negative random variables $\{W_i\}^n$ and a set of $n$ arbitrary iid random variables $\{X_i\}^n$. Assume that for all nonnegative, measurable $f$ with $\mathbb{E}f(X_i) < \infty$ the following condition relating $W_i$ and $X_i$ holds for some $c > 0$:

$$\mathbb{E}\sum_i^n W_i f(X_i) \leq c \mathbb{E}f(X_i)$$

This looks to me like a weaker version of independence, in which case we would have equality for $c = \mathbb{E}\sum_i W_i$. I'm looking for intuition on what this condition guarantees.

For context, this condition is required in the proof of Stone's theorem (1977) proving universal consistency of classifiers based on a weighted partitioning regression estimate of the posterior probability. See Theorem 6.3 in [1] for the proof.

### References

[1] Devroye, L., Gyorfi, L., Lugosi, G. (1997). A Probabilistic Theory of Pattern Recognition Discrete Applied Mathematics  73(2), 192-194. https://dx.doi.org/10.1016/s0166-218x(97)81417-5

Comment: I see, there's really not that much to it. Just bounding the $W_i$ all uniformly by a constant.

Comment: Are you interested in the implications of this condition? There is a summation on the left hand side wrt $i$ while on the rhs there only one index $i$. Is this supposed to hold for all $i$s or.. ?

Comment: Yes. Do you have some deeper intuition on this? The proof mentions it as a technical condition.

Comment: Hmmm... I'll look it up in the book to gain some more insight on the context and will share my thoughts with you tomorrow.

Comment: Having read the theorem and the surrounding context I believe this is some sort of 'sanity' condition. Namely, since $ \sum_i W_{ni}(x) = 1 $, i.e. the $W_{ni}$s are some weights, it is sensible to be able to control the expectation of the weighted average $\sum_i W_{ni}(X)f(X_i)$ by that of $f(X)$, you don't want $\sum_i W_{ni} f(X_i)$ to "explode".